# How to send file parameter in curl using php

Tags: php, curl

how can I send the "file" parameter using curl in php?

This is the API Reference:

```
http --form POST "http://b24.sigurd.bx/rest/upload.json?auth=n2423m863oil59f99c9g0bm4918l5erz&token=disk%7CaWQ9Mjg5Jl89QkYzazEzaXNnUjNHcVZQcDJZaGxGRmI4TGhXOG5EZXQ%3D%7CInVwbG9hZHxkaXNrfGFXUTlNamc1Smw4OVFrWXp
hekV6YVhOblVqTkhjVlpRY0RKWmFHeEdSbUk0VEdoWE9HNUVaWFE9fG4yNDIzbTg2M29pbDU5Zjk5YzlnMGJtNDkxOGw1ZXJ6Ig%3D%3D.Aga709nyY0%2BrFiv3laHjfg6XuOO5JT6ttjU%2F53ifphM%3D" file@~/somelongfile.log
```

I have this Code:

```
                    $uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
                    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $filename;
                    $eol = "\r\n";
                    $data = '';

                    $mime_boundary='----WebKitFormBoundary'.md5(time());

                    $data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
                    $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' . $uploadfile . '"' . $eol;
                    $data .= 'Content-Type: ' . $filetype . $eol .$eol.$eol;
                    $data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . "--";

                    $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                            ": ",
                            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            "Postman-Token: 84f75cb8-6548-420e-ad9b-fb72f40661d2",
                            "cache-control: no-cache",
                            "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$mime_boundary"
                        ),
                    ));
                    $response = curl_exec($curl);
                    $err = curl_error($curl);

                    if ($err) {
                        curl_close($curl);
                        return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
                    }
                    else{
                        curl_close($curl);
                        return json_decode($response);
                    }
```

But I always get this Response:

```
{\"error\":\"DISK_BASE_SERVICE_22001\",\"error_description\":\"Error: required parameter file (DISK_BASE_SERVICE_22001).\"}
```

Using Postman it works and generates following php curl code:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://b24-fyp52c.bitrix24.de/rest/upload.json?auth=29c79b5c002e73c2002e73c000000001e0e3035e6099cf36f62f3c1492d92b9ce7fdd8&token=disk%7CaWQ9ODcmZ2VuZXJhdGVVbmlxdWVOYW1lPTAmXz11bm5LcjRLN1lHYUp2UkRuWjZUU2ZTNjZQaVRwUFNETw%3D%3D%7CInVwbG9hZHxkaXNrfGFXUTlPRGNtWjJWdVpYSmhkR1ZWYm1seGRXVk9ZVzFsUFRBbVh6MTFibTVMY2pSTE4xbEhZVXAyVWtSdVdqWlVVMlpUTmpaUWFWUndVRk5FVHc9PXwyOWM3OWI1YzAwMmU3M2MyMDAyZTczYzAwMDAwMDAwMWUwZTMwMzVlNjA5OWNmMzZmNjJmM2MxNDkyZDkyYjljZTdmZGQ4Ig%3D%3D.u8CkPCbayq3JJ8QJqcAyDKN5EFFAvYmSrksFXcU8oVU%3D%0A",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\kenan\\Pictures\\Bank.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    ": ",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Postman-Token: 84f75cb8-6548-420e-ad9b-fb72f40661d2",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I don't see a difference, from my code to the one of postman but it won't work, any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`CURLFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) object. From the documentation:

```
<?php
/* http://example.com/upload.php:
<?php var_dump($_FILES); ?>
*/

// Create a cURL handle
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = new CURLFile('cats.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');

// Assign POST data
$data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

// Execute the handle
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but it still says the "file" parameter is missing.

Comment: Edit your question and show your attempt using `CURLFile`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like so:

```
exec ("curl -X POST -F 'file=@" . $uploadfile . "' '" . $url . "'");
```

Is there a way to do this, the old fashion curl way? Or this anyway the only solution?

Thank you!